# How to make tab bar disappear when navigating to details page

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, maui, tabbar

I am trying to implement the simple following navigation scenario:

I have "Page 1", which has a tab bar, and it allows navigation to "DetailsPage" which is defined as a global route, and only displays a back button to navigate back to  "Page 1". This video shows this scenario exactly: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/74175405/229085788-05809927-904b-4503-8b33-c8a45204e7a2.mp4

I have tried different approaches usingthe Shell.SetTabarIsVisible method but without success, the last one that I have tried after doing some researches and that seems the most cohesive is doing this respectively in FirstPage.xaml.cs and DetailsPage.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(workoutSelectionPage, false); //This is Page 2, in page 1 I set true 
}
```

AppShell.xaml:

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Page 1">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:FirstPage}"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("Page 2", typeof(DetailsPage));
```

This is a pretty basic scenario so I'm sure I am missing something simple here any input is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to set **SetTabBarIsVisible** in DetailPage.

The following code could be used to achieve the scenario in the video.

***AppShell.xaml***, don't need to set the ShellContent for DetailPage.

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="MainPage">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="First Page">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:FirstPage}"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

***AppShell.cs***, register routes here,

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("mainpage", typeof(MainPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute("firstpage", typeof(FirstPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute("detailpage", typeof(DetailPage));
```

***FirstPage.cs***, use shell navigation,

```
async void Navigate()
{
    ...
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("detailpage");
}
```

***DetailPage.cs***, use **SetTabBarIsVisible** in OnAppearing or constructor

```
public DetailPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false);
}
```

This is the effect:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I should be as easy as putting it in the Ctor:

```cs
public TestView(TestViewModel viewModel)
{
    BindingContext = _viewModel = viewModel;

    InitializeComponent();

    Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false);
}
```

Alternativ to set it on the xaml page

```xml
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiTest.Views.TestView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
    Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False">
```

Comment: That it indeed what I thought and the first approach I tried (putting it in the ctor that is). Unfortunately that doesn't do it, I can with this approach hide the bar in Page1 but not on DetailsPage. It is related to navigation it seems: "FirstPage/DetailsPage" does not allow DetailsPage to modify the tab bar visibility because it "belongs" to FirstPage. That is why I also tried to set the tab bar visibility to false in FirstPage when navigation to DetailsPage is triggered, but it does nothing, like the page must be refreshed manually or something. Maybe it is the way to go...

Comment: I understand. You need to give us complete code of the Pages involved.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"` does work, however you'll have to set it for the child page you open from the tab, as well as any children you open from the new page. I dislike the idea of setting the boolean throughout the app, especially because the Xamarin version of the tab bar & navigation would open a new page without the tab bar when you navigated from inside the tab.

I created `ShyTab` to mimic the Xamarin tab, where the tab bar is hidden when you open a page from that tab.

```
/// <summary>
/// A tab for a tab bar that will hide the tab bar when navigation happens inside of the page. 
/// </summary>
public class ShyTab : ShellContent
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when the content in the tab appears.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        //we need to tell the tab bar to hide itself, otherwise the second page we navigate to will have the tabbar again.
        //We can access the tab bar by referencing the parent of the tab, this.Parent.
        Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this.Parent, true);
        Shell.Current.Navigating += HideTabBar;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when the content in the tab disappears
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        Shell.Current.Navigating -= HideTabBar;
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }

    private void HideTabBar(object? sender, ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        //When switching between the tabs, the Current and Target are the same,
        //so we can use that to tell if we are changing the tab or going to a new page.
        if (e.Current.Location != e.Target.Location)
        {
            Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this.Parent, false);
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

Create your tab with a ShyTab in-place of a ShellContent

```
<Shell>
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent x:Name="myTab1"
                Title="MyTab1"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate MyTab1Page}"/>
        <ShyTab x:Name="myTab2"
                Title="MyTab2"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate MyTab2Page}"/>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```